# Images in Google data studio dashboard working for editor but not working for viewer

Tags: looker-studio

I use google form to collect images. The images are stored in a folder in google drive. The folder is shared publicly so that all the photos within the folder are also public if the link is available. The responses are stored in google sheet and converted to a accessible file that i.e. change from "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" to "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" so that images are directly accessible. The google sheet is connected with google data studio. I need to show these images in the data studio dashboard. What I could find as solution was to create a table with the image URLs. Using a table, I've tried to do the following

1. Created a new field in google data studio and added image function with a link as mentioned above.
2. Instead of creating a new field, changed the type of image URL column to URL as well as image.

Both above are working for me as an editor (during edit or view as shared in below images. But when I share the dashboard as a link and view it in incognito mode, it is not working. I hope I'm able to explain.

Google Form Link: https://forms.gle/FFjX7cV8tJUSx5GW9

Google sheet where data is collected : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1glpAId0LHgTUUtVk3RwakDr-H1KUXk3WtA-SE50HKXQ/edit?usp=sharing + also Embedded in google data studio

Google Data Studio link: https://datastudio.google.com/s/oaCN4EO-J4c

[Its working for me as editor, but as a viewer in above link, its not working as visible in above data studio link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByBdv.png)

[But as a viewer (incognito mode) images are not visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5gC7.png)

Comment: Hi !
This is strange. I tried to reproduce this issue. I used two google accounts and two browsers. Well, in Chrome the reports work for both user! This is the good news.

Comment: In Chromes  incognito mode it shows no picture. In firefox it also shows no picture. Even if the dataset comes from BigQuery, the url does not show the picture in these cases.


However, I added a field with another picture url ("https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-july-27-6753651837109019-l.png"). This picture is shown in all cases.


So I am completly puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the images work for any user logged into its own Google account.  The problem is really experienced when the dashboard is open with no logged user.

Diving into the problem, it seems to be related with the number of redirects that Google Drive need to access the image.  Reproducing your dashboard I was able to see the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in browser's Dev Mode.

Steps in logged mode:

1. Access `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[id]`
2. 302 Redirect to `https://*.googleusercontent.com/docs/`
3. The image is returned

Steps in non logged mode:

1. Access `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[id]`
2. 302 Redirect to `https://*.googleusercontent.com/docs/...`
3. 302 Redirect to `https://docs.google.com/nonceSigner?...`
4. The image is returned

If you look into Dev Mode, it is possible to note that the URL ended with "/nonceSigner" is accessed dozens of times when not logged (the same does not happen when logged).  This means that **Data Studio start a loop trying to access the image, which triggers a "retry" operation when it sees a double redirect**.

Curiously, this does not happen when using the standard Image control (instead of table chart, that reads from a DataSource), so it seems to be a bug in the Table chart component.

So you're out of luck.  My suggestion is to use Cloud Storage instead of Google Drive, since it seems you're using some undocumented features and they'll surely break at some time.

Another option is to report this bug to DataStudio team ([report here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/support)). There are Data Studio developers that activelly answer questions in StackOverflow (like [Minhaz Kazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4024072/minhaz-kazi)), so try to drive their attention to this issue.

Comment: Cannot use any other medium except google drive. The Google Form uploads the files in google drive only and adds the link of uploaded file in the survey answers as a link. I will have to manually transfer and update each link.

Comment: This solution is a workaround, so you really should not expect it to be a comfortable solution until they fix the bug. In several situations, I often have to copy files from Google Drive to Cloud Storage to achieve some goal (particularlly because BigQuery can read several files at once from there), and I use Cloud Functions to automate this task.

Comment: Hey @Diego, this seems to have been fixed, or I'm being paranoid. Can you check and confirm? Basically  https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[id] is now visible to non logged in user as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a related issue here - a colleague was not able to view images in a data studio dashboard, even though he was able to view the same files directly in Drive. It turned out to only be a problem using the Brave browser! I can't figure out what exactly was going on, but posting here in case it helps someone else.